# I want to use dynamic result in a different query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on a query that would use the top average from one query and compare it with the value that is already been stored in a different column.

The first query is as follows

```
SELECT  top 1
        CONVERT(varchar, md_settlementdate, 23) [Day of Year], 
        SUM(MD_KVA)/8 [Average KVA30], 
        SUM(MD_KVA15)/8 [Average KVA15]
                
FROM tblMeter INNER JOIN dbX.dbo.tblMeterData ON M_ID = MD_MeterID
WHERE   M_MeterRef = @NMI
        AND MD_SettlementDate >= @startdate -- 366
        AND MD_SettlementDate <= @enddate
        AND MD_KVA >= 0
        --AND (CONVERT(TIME,md_settlementdate,108) BETWEEN '17:30:00.0000000' AND '21:00:00.0000000') 
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, md_settlementdate, 23)
ORDER BY [Average KVA30] desc
```

This is the result

| Day of Year | Average KVA30 | Average KVA15 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-12-24 | 300.785712 | 314.308450 |

My second query is

```
    Select C_Name, M_MeterRef  , 
MI_InvoiceNo,MI_StartDate, 
MI_AccountNo, IC_Description,
ICHT_Description, IC_Qty, IC_AuditQty, IC_Qty - IC_AuditQty As Variance
    from tblMeter
    inner join rest_of_Tables
```

The result is basically all the columns that I have called for.

What I really want is that the M_MeterRef in table 1 matches with M_MeterRef in the second table and the last column has the Top 1 average for that particular M_MeterRef

I have tried using nested queries, CASE but I have no luck.

My tried query which had no luck

```
Select C_Name, M_MeterRef m , MI_InvoiceNo,MI_StartDate, MI_AccountNo, IC_Description,ICHT_Description, IC_Qty, IC_AuditQty, IC_Qty - IC_AuditQty As Variance,
 case when N_ID = 1556 then (SELECT  top 1
        
        SUM(MD_KVA15)/8 [Average KVA15]
        
FROM tblMeter INNER JOIN dbCES_MeterUpload.dbo.tblMeterData ON M_ID = MD_MeterID
WHERE   M_MeterRef = @NMI
        AND MD_SettlementDate >= @startdate -- 366
        AND MD_SettlementDate <= @enddate
        AND MD_KVA >= 0
        
        AND (CONVERT(TIME,md_settlementdate,108) BETWEEN '17:30:00.0000000' AND '21:00:00.0000000') /* REST OF SA */
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, md_settlementdate, 23)
ORDER BY [Average KVA30] desc) END AS X
```

and rest being the same. I get a value that is static. I want the query to first match with MeterRef in the second query and the show the value for that MEterRef

Comment: May be you can reduce the where condition statement,inner join statement and select column which is not relate to the question,just like cut the leaf left the branch.And it's also well to use simple symbol like a,b,c to replace your real column and table name.

Comment: `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`  means that you have three column return in you subquery, but you use it as one column 'X'

Comment: After removing two columns from the sub query, i do get a value. This value is static. What I mean is that this value is from the first query where M_meterRef = NMI is mentioned. I have almost 800 M_MeterRef that need to be compared with the matching M_MeterRef in the second query and output table @ElapsedSoul

Comment: Remove the condition "M_MeterRef = @NMI", move the column "M_MeterRef " to group by statement of first sql.Then use it to link to the second sql

Comment: I did the first bit, but I do not understand the second bit of your solution @ElapsedSoul

Answer (score 1):

```sql
Select C_Name, M_MeterRef  , 
MI_InvoiceNo,MI_StartDate, 
MI_AccountNo, IC_Description,
ICHT_Description, IC_Qty, IC_AuditQty, IC_Qty - IC_AuditQty As Variance,a.KVA30
    from tblMeter b ,(SELECT  top 1
        CONVERT(varchar, md_settlementdate, 23) [Day of Year], M_MeterRef ,
        SUM(MD_KVA)/8 [Average KVA30], 
        SUM(MD_KVA15)/8 [Average KVA15]
FROM tblMeter group by M_MeterRef ,CONVERT(varchar, md_settlementdate, 23)) a
where a.M_MeterRef =b.M_MeterRef
```

I guess this is what you want?

Comment: If this is what you need,you can learn lead function to optimize the sql